# C++ asynchronous function in Windows

Tags: c++, function, asynchronous, draw, points

I am back with an experimental project that starts with this:
I have an array of 10000 elements of *POINT* type. They are supposed to be pixels with x and y coordinate, to be drawn on a window (*SetPixel()*). I have created a simple function that creates the DC, get each POINT from the array and draws it on the screen:

```
void draw_points() {
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        SetPixel(hdc, points[i].x, points[i].y, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    }
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
}
```

Well, I placed this function inside the main loop of the *WinMain()* function. It works. I can see the points being drawn on the screen. The problem is that while the points are being displayed I can't do anything else, so I found out that I would need asynchronous functions, like in Java. That's because I would like to be able to add, remove, modify points from the array while the **draw_points()** function is running.

I don't need any result from it, I just want it to run in another thread while I do whatever I want with other functions.
So, my question: what does Windows API offer me for this? Which is the usual way to do it? Do I need some external library? I just don't know how to start. I hope you understand what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call this from the main loop. Instead you should call it when you get a [`WM_PAINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event in your window message loop.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want it to run only when WM_PAINT is called, I want it to run constantly

Comment: @ali Call it in `WM_PAINT`, and if you change some points call e.g. [`RedrawWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`UpdateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145167%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and you will get a `WM_PAINT` event. _Never_ draw unless you really have to.

Comment: Yes, that could be a good alternative. I understand that async threads are not very used in such cases

Comment: Yet, I have to use asynchronous function because a loop through 10000 POINT elements will always freeze my window, wherever it is started.

Comment: @ali If you put it in a thread, you shouldn't be drawing on the actual window DC. Instead create a new DC and bitmap, and draw on that, then on `WM_PAINT` do a `BitBlt` from the DC you draw on to the actual window DC.

Comment: @ali You also said you want to be able to remove and modify points? You definitely want an off-screen bitmap. Erasing and redrawing 10000 points on the primary DC will not look good. In fact, you might want to consider some sort of hardware acceleration such as OpenGL or Direct3D, since that many SetPixel() operations is not very efficient. I would look into point sprites.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you cannot do anything is because you're not responding to Windows messages. You should put a PeekMessage() call in your loop to periodically check the message queue. When you get one, you need to call TranslateMessage() and DispatchMessage().

Comment: That's how I do it. Yet, the loop freezes a little bit the window (10000 elements, imagine)